# Determine whether $d_s(p,q)= \sin |p-q|$ is a metric on $[0,\pi/2).$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, proof-verification, metric-spaces, definition

The following problem is taken from 'Real Mathematical Analysis' by Pugh $2$nd edition, page $125,$ exercise $6.$

> For $p,q \in [0,\pi/2)$ let    $$d_s(p,q)= \sin |p-q|.$$  Use your
>   calculus talent to decide whether $d_s$ is a metric.

My attempt:

Clearly for any $p,q \in [0,\pi/2),$ $d_s(p,q) \geq 0.$

If $p=q,$ then we have $d_s(p,q) = \sin |p - p| = 0.$

If $d_s(p,q) = 0,$ then $\sin |p-q| = 0.$
As sine function is injective on $[0,\pi/2),$ we have $|p - q| = 0,$ which implies that $p = q.$

For any $p,q \in \in [0,\pi/2),$ we have $d_s(p,q) = \sin |p - q| = \sin |q - p| = d_s(q,p).$

Let $p,q,r \in [0,\pi/2).$ 
Since $d_s(p,q) = d_s(q,p),$ without loss of generality, we assume that $p \geq q \geq r.$
Observe that
$$d_s(p,r) \leq d_s(p,q) + d_s(q,r)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sin(p-r) \leq \sin(p-q) + \sin(q-r)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2 \sin \left( \frac{p-r}{2} \right) \cos \left( \frac{p-r}{2} \right) \leq 2 \sin \left( \frac{p-r}{2} \right) \cos \left( \frac{p-2q +r}{2} \right)$$ 
    $$\Leftrightarrow \cos \left( \frac{p-r}{2} \right) \leq \cos \left( \frac{p- 2q + r}{2} \right)$$ 
Since cosine function is decreasing and $\frac{p-r}{2}, \frac{p-2q+r}{2} \in [0,\pi/4),$  we have
    $$\Leftrightarrow \frac{p-r}{2} \geq \frac{p-2q+r}{2}$$
    $$\Leftrightarrow q \geq r.$$
    Since the last inequality holds, we have $d_s(p,r) \leq d_s(p,q) + d_s(q,r).$

Hence, $d_s$ is a metric.

**I am not very sure about triangle inequality part.** Can anyone check my proof? Thanks.

Comment: you have to assume that $p \geq q \geq r$ if you want to remove the absolute value

Comment: Oops, I got the inequality the other way round. But wouldn't it give me $q = r?$

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima no its is enough on $[0, \pi/2)$

Comment: @Idonknow no because you canot remove the cos in your inequality like that. You have to check on which interval are the arguments of the cos. And on $[0, \pi/2)$, cos is decreasing for example

Comment: @fonfonx: Oops, I made a lot of mistakes. You are right.

Comment: @fonfonx: Edtied.

Comment: what does a metric even mean

Comment: I think it is correct now. But you have to say that either $p-2q+r$ is non negative (and below $/pi$) so you can use the fact that cos is non increasing, or that it is negative and in that case the inequality is trivial

Comment: @SakethMalyala https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easie. For $x\in [-\pi/2; \pi/2]$ we have $\sin |x|=|\sin x|$, therefore  $\sin|p-r|=|\sin(p-r)|=|\sin(p-q)\cos(q-r)+\sin(q-r)\cos(p-q)|\leq |\sin(p-q)|+|\sin(q-r)|=\sin|p-q|+\sin|q-r|.$

Comment: Nice and tidy proof.

Comment: I think the interval should be $(-\pi/2,\pi/2).$

Comment: @Idonknow, If something is true for  $|x|\le \pi/2$ then its true for $|x|< \pi/2$